# Combining VLOOKUP() Functionality with QUERY() in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with the following [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ/edit#gid=0).

`Sheet1` consists of the following query functions:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!C8:N"), "Select Col10+Col11+Col12 where Col1 = 'A' label Col10+Col11+Col12 ''"))
```

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!C8:N"), "Select Col10+Col11+Col12 where Col1 = 'B' label Col10+Col11+Col12 ''"))
```

The above query functions return the sum of row values of Columns L, M, N from `Sheet2` for products `A` and `B`

I would like to have the returned values matched with their respective `Date` and `0` returned if no entry for `A` or `B` exists on `Sheet2` for that `Date`.

Please Advise.

Comment: Add another condition with date to `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Harun24HR Would you mind explaining your comment a bit more?

Comment: I am not sure which column contains date to your source sheet. Suppose it is in `Col5` then use `WHERE` clause like `where Col1 = 'A' AND Col5=" & C3 & " label Col10+ .....` Here `C3` is date cell to your result sheet.

Comment: Please Refer to the Attached Google Sheet Link on the first line

Comment: @Harun24HR I actually have an entire row of Dates that need to be matched with the returned values rather than just one cell, would your solution work in that case too?

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS()`. I think `SUMIFS()` may work.

Comment: Haven't tried SUMIFS()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot` within `query` will give you a similar result to your expected output on your sample sheet (I've removed the `importrange` on the test example):

```
=Arrayformula(query({Sheet2!C8:C,Sheet2!D8:D,Sheet2!L8:L+Sheet2!M8:M+Sheet2!N8:N},"select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Products' ",0))
```

[image]

The `pivot` data is formatted 'yyyy-mm-dd' but if you want it as entered on Sheet2:

```
=Arrayformula({"Products",transpose(sort(unique(query({Sheet2!D8:D},"where Col1 is not null",0)),1,1));query(query({Sheet2!C8:C,Sheet2!D8:D,Sheet2!L8:L+Sheet2!M8:M+Sheet2!N8:N},"select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 ",0),"offset 1",0)})
```

[image]

Where there is `0` values on a given date the result is `0`. Where there are no dates for A or B, the result is blank. The empty values are not quite what you asked for but they do indicate where there are no dates in the data.

Both examples with the `importrange` added back in:

```
=Arrayformula(query({IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!C8:C"),IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!D8:D"),IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!L8:L")+IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!M8:M")+IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!N8:N")},"select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Products' ",0))
```

and:

```
=Arrayformula({"Products",transpose(sort(unique(query({IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!D8:D")},"where Col1 is not null",0)),1,1));query(query({IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!C8:C"),IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!D8:D"),IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!L8:L")+IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!M8:M")+IMPORTRANGE("1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ", "Sheet2!N8:N")},"select Col1,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 ",0),"offset 1",0)})
```

It might be more manageable to reference the URL from a cell or named range in your sheet, eg:

`IMPORTRANGE(A1, "Sheet2!D8:D")`

where `A1` is the cell containing `1JIAydWLj85vtcSkqNjINv9Ab5n7aX8y9XBY5fP-NQSQ`.

Comment: It's a Great Answer! Would it possible to use `IMPORTRANGE()` in your answer too? As I see you've done this `Sheet2!C8:C,Sheet2!D8:D,Sheet2!L8:L+Sheet2!M8:M+Sheet2!N8:N` and I'm not sure if I could plug that into an  `IMPORTRANGE()' function

Comment: Yes you can replace each range `Sheet2!C8:C` with `importrange("xxxx","Sheet2!C8:C")`. So that would be 5 importranges. Alternatively, you could importrange the main data onto another sheet in the doc and then update the formula to reference the sheet. Solution updated.